# How to fix eclipse font in Windows 8.1

Tags: eclipse, windows, fonts

I have Eclipse Mars and Windows 8.1. When I open Eclipse my font looks like below:
[image]

On other PC with Windows 8.1 font looks differently:
[image]

I've fixed this once by running Eclipse in Windows 7 compatibility mode but it doesn't work for my current PC.

Does anyone know some solution for this problem?

**UPD**: On Windows 8.1 default font is "Courier New" and on bottom picture it's "Consolas"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are using a Serif font in the top screenshot, and sans serif in the bottom. The text does not appear "blurry" as such.

That said, you can configure the font in `Preferences -> General -> Appearance -> Colors and Fonts`

Comment: Yes actually the top text font is "Courier New" and the bottom is "Consolas". I thought that it just blurred. Thanks